# Absolute value meta programming

Tags: c++, template, integer, casting

I am implementing a generic absolute value function that handles signed and unsigned integer values correctly over the input type's domain. The `std::abs(...)` function leaves the case of `std::abs(INT_MIN)` as undefined behavior [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs). I hope to resolve the undefined behavior by representing the returned absolute value in the input type's corresponding unsigned type. For example,

```
int input = INT_MIN; // -2147483648
unsigned output = integral::abs(input);
```

will correctly return 2147483648, but as an unsigned type.

To accomplish this I implemented the following,

```
    namespace integral
    {
        template<typename integral_value_t>
        auto
        abs(integral_value_t const val)
        {
            static_assert(std::is_integral<integral_value_t>::value);
            if(val < 0)
            {
                return static_cast<
                       typename std::make_unsigned<integral_value_t>::type>(-val);
            }
            return static_cast<
                       typename std::make_unsigned<integral_value_t>::type>(val);
        }
    }
```

but it created some concerns.

**Concerns:**

1. Returning an unsigned type creates a type management challenge for the caller.
2. Maybe there is a better name for the function or namespace?
3. Is the `typename` keyword required in `static_cast<typename`(gcc 12.1 complained)?
4. Can the make_unsigned<...> call be made once? Making it twice is overly verbose.

The code is also available on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/s7e7dhGW9).

Comment: One thing you could do, not long enough to be an answer, is `integral_value_t new_value = val < 0 ? -val : val;`, and then return the `make_unsigned<...>` with that new value.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it got me thinking about using a using statement to store the type. For example `using return_t = std::make_unsigned<integral_value_t>(val)::type`. See [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/11jehE5v8) for concrete example.

Comment: @Linny That would not work. Consider the type of the result of the expression `-val` if `val` is an `int` and its value is `INT_MIN`. Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37301078/is-negating-int-min-undefined-behaviour).

Comment: BTW, there's no [tag:template-meta-programming] here - it's just straightforward template code.  I've edited tags appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific concern (3): yes, the `typename` keyword is required, because at parse time the type `std::make_unsigned<integral_value_t>` isn't known, so its `type` member could be an object as far as the compiler is concerned.  It's only once `integral_value_t` is known that it becomes a complete type.

---

For concern (4), I'd recommend a `using` statement to avoid repeating the long type name.

---

We should include the `<type_traits>` header so that our function is usable immediately.

---

Instead of the `static_assert`, I'd use a constraint to make the non-integral overloads disappear.  Perhaps:

```
auto abs(std::integral auto&& val)
```

It might even be worth constraining to accept only signed types, though that could inhibit its use in generic code.

---

It looks like we're assuming 2's-complement representation, given that `-INT_MAX` is undefined in standard C++.  The `if`/`else` seems to be duplicating `std::abs()`, so why not call that?  It's no more undefined than `-val` is.

To eliminate undefined behaviour, we can't simply use `-val` in all cases.  I'd do it by adding to `val` until it is large enough to be negated without overflow:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>

namespace integral
{
    template<std::unsigned_integral T>
    auto abs(T&& val)
    {
        return val;
    }

    template<std::signed_integral T>
    auto abs(T&& val)
    {
        using U = typename std::make_unsigned_t<T>;

        if (val >= 0) {
            return static_cast<U>(val);
        }

        static constexpr auto maxval = std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
        U retval = 0;
        while (val < -maxval) {
            val += maxval;
            retval += maxval;
        }
        return retval - val;
    }
}
```

I *think* it's guaranteed that the `while` will only ever perform one iteration, but I can't find where the standard says that negative range of signed types can only be slightly greater than their positive range.

Comment: Ouch, that `while`-loop is super confusing to read. And is it even correct? If you need to increment `val` twice, wouldn't that be very likely to cause `retval` to overflow?

Comment: It shouldn't do (as `retval` is of the unsigned type).  I'm not sure it's even permitted for `INT_MIN` to be less than `-2 * INT_MAX`, or the equivalent for any other signed type.  Do you have a suggestion for making it clearer (perhaps change the condition to `val + maxval < 0`?  Or better variable names?) or for an alternative, but safe, implementation?

Comment: *"I can't find where the standard says that negative range of signed types can only be slightly greater than their positive range."* Is there equivalent guaranty that `-std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` is in range? :-)

Comment: That's a good question too, @Jarod.  I guess some detailed standards-diving is required for a completely robust implementation; unfortunately I don't have time to do that right now.  :-(

Comment: https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#1 for C++20 (2's complement mandatory).